# How to calculate table offsets

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am looking for a cost effective way of accessing records in my 6502 table.
The table is 8 bytes long.  Using indrect Y, I can offset the fields, but I
want a way to get to the next 0th record.

I have thought about:

```
lda #id
adc #$08
tax ; now x = x + 8
```

I have seen others who use ASL while the accumulator has a value that is a power
of 2 to do:

```
asl a
tax ; x = x * 2
```

That would be great if I only had 2 records, but if I ASL again, the result will be x = 32.
This would be too far of an offset.

Is there a better way to do this than using ADC?

Comment: You say the table is 8 bytes long, but it looks like you mean the records are 8 bytes long and the table is several records. How big is the table?

Comment: For a table 8 bytes long, just iterate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the table is actually several 8 bytes records, I would store it as 8 1-byte record tables, which can be efficiently indexed.

i.e struct of arrays, rather than array of structs

This has the advantage of allowing the indexing of 256 records with just register offsets, and also the use of different sized records without changing the address calculation (so if you want 5-byte records, you just use less arrays, rather than changing the calculations).

```
LDA ELEMENT1,Y ; This is an array of the first bytes of our record
STA $1000
LDA ELEMENT2,Y ; This is the second bytes...
STA $1001
...etc...
INY            ; Just need to inc Y to access next record
```

As `INX`/`INY` are 2-cycle instructions, you're not going to beat that for updating an index.

This is my primary recommendation as it's fast and simple, though it does mean reformatting your data.

If this isn't an option you could either reformat the data dynamically such that it *is* (assuming you're going to then access it enough that it's worth the cost, and you have space to do so), or else you could use a variety of techniques, depending on how you actually want to access the data, and how important performance is.

If you really need to add an arbitrary amount to an index, rather than just increment, then the naive way to do it would be:

```
TYA      (2)
CLC      (2)
ADC #amt (2)
TAY      (2)
```

Howver that naive version takes 8 cycles. You can do it in 6 cycles if you omit the clear-carry, which you can do in cases where you *know* that it's already been cleared (for example, if following some other loop calculation where being in the loop implies that a carry has not been generated). So it can be worth juggling the code around to avoid setting flags. Anything less than incrementing by 4 could be done simply by incrementing multiple times.

If you cannot guarantee that carry is cleared, but you can spare a page in memory for a lookup table, then you could store 0 -> 255 in the bytes in that page and do:

```
LDA table + amt, Y (4)
TAY                (2)
```

The carry flag isn't set by that, but the zero flag is, so if the table wraps around to zero, you can check for that.

If you have to index off an address, then you could do:

```
LDA (zeropagevector), Y
```

And increment the high-byte of `zeropagevector`. However that takes 5 cycles for the read. If you are only reading from your record in a single instruction, you could simply use normal absolute addressing, and modify the address in the instruction itself, saving a cycle.

Basically, there are loads of ways to optimise this kind of thing in 6502, but it really depends on exactly what your data is and how you want to access it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have 2 bytes (16 bits) for table pointer variable is your data is longer than a 256 bytes block.

```
    tablePointerLo = $fa ; example zeropage value
    tablePointerHi = $fb ; example zeropage value

    tableAddress = $1000 ; example table address

    tableLength = 100*8 ; example length
    tableEnd = tableAddress + tableLength

    lda #<tableAddress
    sta tablePointerLo
    lda #>tableAddress
    sta tablePointerHi

loop02:
    ldy #$00
loop01:
    lda (tablePointerLo),y
    sta anywhereYouWant,y
    iny
    cpy #$08
    bne loop01

    lda tablePointerLo
    clc
    adc #$08
    sta tablePointerLo
    bcc pass01
    inc tablePointerHi
pass01:

    ; do whatever you want here with the datas

    lda tablePointerLo
    cmp #<tableEnd
    bne loop02
    lda tablePointerHi
    cmp #>tableEnd
    bne loop02
```

I didn't test the code, it may not work but you should get the main idea.